# How to override customize_show Attribute in Odoo 11?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-11

Module `website` has this template:

```
<template id="footer_default" inherit_id="website.footer_custom" customize_show="True" name="Automatic Footer">
    <xpath expr="//div[@id='footer']" position="replace">
        ...
    </xpath>
</template>
```

They are setting the `customize_show` attribute and I want to to override it to false in my module to get rid of the option in the customize menu.

I tried this and serveral other ways:

```
<template id="footer_default" inherit_id="website.footer_custom" customize_show="False" active="False" name="Automatic Footer">
</template>
```

But I guess the problem is that mine is `my_module.footer_default` so I won't be able to override it that way i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try updating the `ir.ui.view` record of the template directly:

```xml
<record id="website.footer_default" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="customize_show" eval="False"/>
</record>
```

Comment: Works just like a charm.
Thanks alot.